# How to post on someone else's page wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I've created a business page and a profile for myself, but when I post on someone else's community page wall the post is only visible to my friends. The posts are not visible if I log out either. I've tried posting with my personal profile, and as my business page and I've tried things like @-tagging and liking the pages I'm trying to post on.

How do you do this?

It's really frustrating, since I can see other people posting on the walls I'm trying to post myself.

Comment: Your question is not clear but I think you can't see the post when you logout of Facebook is because of the security settings of that particular page where you are posting.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a security settings issue. It could be that your post security is set to friends only, or that the page owner has their page security set that way.